# Get users by nested property in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I have some nested code I'm trying to access in Firebase. I understand how to access in the second_user, but the first I'm not sure how.

I have the code that works for the second below, but not the first. How do I do the same thing?

```
ref.child('users')
  .orderByChild('username')
  .equalTo(username)
  .once('value', function (snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val())
  })
```

for this data below

```
users {
    "first_user" : {
      "info" : {
        "admin" : false,
        "email" : "adaaasds",
        "first" : "Sam",
        "last" : "Cassell",
        "username" : "samcassell"
      }
    },
    "second_user" : {
      "admin" : false,
      "email" : "johndoe@gmail.com",
      "first" : "john",
      "last" : "doe",
      "username" : "johndoe"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query data structured like the `first_user` in your example, you would specify the deep path to the child:

```js
ref.child('users')
  .orderByChild('info/username')
  .equalTo(username)
  .once('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      console.log(childSnapshot.key, JSON.stringify(childSnapshot.val()));
    });
  })
```

For queries where you expect only a single child to match, you could call `limitToFirst` and could use `forEach` like this:

```js
ref.child('users')
  .orderByChild('info/username')
  .equalTo(username)
  .limitToFirst(1)
  .once('value', function (snapshot) {
    var user;
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) { user = childSnapshot.val(); });
    if (user) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(child.val()));
    } else {
      console.log('User not found.');
    }
  })
```

Comment: with that, is there any way to retrieve the object returned from snapshot.val()? . e.g. it returns `Object {firstUser: Object}`. the only way i can think is `Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0]`, but that seems messy

Comment: I've updated the answer. Clearly, my previous comment was bonkers. I should wait till I've had my morning coffee before answering anything, really.

Comment: i actually just switched to using once('child_added') instead. didnt think it was that big a of deal!

Comment: Using `once('child_added')` is a neat solution, but if the key doesn't exist, nothing will happen (unless it's added later). Might not be a problem, but it's something to bear in mind.